# Can MICE pool results of ordinal logistic regression run by the function polr()?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, ordinal, r-mice

I'm running the data set downloaded from UCLA

```
read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/ologit.dta")
```

and randomly assign some missing values in the independent variables: pared, public, and gpa. Then I use mice to generate imputed values and run the ordinal logistic regression for the 5 complete data set with imputed values.

```
DAT.imp=mice(DAT,print=FALSE)
DAT.fit.mice.plr = with(DAT.imp, polr(apply ~ pared + public + gpa))
summary(DAT.fit.mice.plr)
```

But the error message shows as follows:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
 cannot coerce class ""polr"" to a data.frame
```

Is it a problem because the pool() function cannot run models not belong to lm?
Should I run the model by polr() separately for the 5 imputed data sets and manually pool them?
Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to  install the newest versions of packages with depencies:

`install.packages(c("mice", "MASS"), dep = TRUE)`

and got results
`> summary(pool(mod))
                                estimate std.error  statistic       df      p.value
pared                        1.088364240 0.2675445  4.0679748 388.8699 5.744000e-05
public                      -0.007057661 0.3020328 -0.0233672 376.9368 9.813694e-01
gpa                          0.628030991 0.2610602  2.4056945 387.3003 1.660783e-02
unlikely|somewhat likely     2.250628213 0.7816727  2.8792461 386.0658 4.206607e-03
somewhat likely|very likely  4.353582378 0.8076085  5.3907086 385.6545 1.219831e-07`
 
and

`> pool(mod)
Class: mipo    m = 5 
                                estimate       ubar            b          t dfcom       df
pared                        1.088364240 0.07111586 0.0003868321 0.07158006   395 388.8699
public                      -0.007057661 0.08973729 0.0012387621 0.09122381   395 376.9368
gpa                          0.628030991 0.06759665 0.0004631305 0.06815241   395 387.3003
unlikely|somewhat likely     2.250628213 0.60530521 0.0047558921 0.61101228   395 386.0658
somewhat likely|very likely  4.353582378 0.64589464 0.0052807731 0.65223157   395 385.6545`

`riv      lambda        fmi
pared                         0.006527356 0.006485026 0.01155566
public                        0.016565181 0.016295247 0.02147350
gpa                           0.008221658 0.008154614 0.01323709
unlikely|somewhat likely      0.009428418 0.009340353 0.01443286
somewhat likely|very likely   0.009811086 0.009715764 0.01481172`

which are slightly different. The reported statistics are also slightly different. I'm not sure it is correct(only due to imputations). However the codes run well without error.